# How to redirect user to first accessible child-subsite from parent-site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site, sub-site, redirect

I would like to find a way how to redirect each user to first accessible subsite in SharePoint 2013.

I have an example of sites' structure:

- MAIN SITE (homepage with links to sites)

  - Site1
    -Subsite1    -Subsite2    -Subsite3    -Subsite4
  - Site2
    -Subsite5    -Subsite6    -Subsite7
  - Site3
    -Subsite8    -Subsite9    -Subsite10    -Subsite11    -Subsite12

I need to automatically redirect SP user from Site1 to Subsite1 or (if user has no permissions to subsite1) Subsite2 (or) Subsite3 (or) Subsite4.

This solution should be implemented on each site (1,2,3).

Can somebody help me?

EDIT:

I have now a trouble with executing code (function runCode()):

```
var webCollection = null;

function runCode() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        this.webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
        clientContext.load(this.webCollection);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var webName = "";
    var webEnumerator = this.webCollection.getEnumerator();
    webEnumerator.moveNext();
        var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
        webName += web.get_title(); 
    window.location.href = "http://sharepoint/sites/m1/s/" + webName;
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get a fully worked solution on each site in SharePoint.

It needs to be pasted in **default.aspx** under the tag:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
```

Here is the js code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >

var webCollection = null;

function runCode() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        this.webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
        clientContext.load(this.webCollection);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var webName = "";
    var webEnumerator = this.webCollection.getEnumerator();
    webEnumerator.moveNext();
    var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
    webName += web.get_url(); 
    window.location.href = webName;
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
window.setTimeout(function(){runCode()},0);


</script>
```

**IMPORTANT!**

I must notice that first subsite is the first **created** subsite.

If somebody moves the hyperlinks in top navigation bar, it doesn't matter for above redirection method - it always moves to the first **created** (by admin or developer) subsite!

Answer (score 1):

You could check SharePoint REST API to make ajax request and perform your expected behavior.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819.aspx#bk_WebGetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser

You could also take time to learn how to use JSOM API to do the same think (but too heavy to implement if you have not a friendly framework :)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246242.aspx

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the first solution you presented works only in SharePoint Online but I use SharePoint Server and the second solution was found previously by me and it doesn't work. I tried to implement it in both: default.aspx by SharePoint Designer and Script Editor Web Part. I need other solutions.

Comment: The second solution shows only a button but without result after click - I see only a text: ''Child sites of the current site:'...

Comment: Could you share your code used in the second solution? Maybe something is missing.

Comment: I just copied and pasted code from MSDN. I don't think it's a problem with missing code.

Comment: Sometimes, scripts are not loaded correctly. Check with this:
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
    // Your code
    });

Comment: Hi, the second solution finally worked. It shows a list of subsites which are accessible to user. When I try to make a small modification in the code which should allow me to show only the first subsite, nothing happens after clicking the buton.

Comment: function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var webEnumerator = this.webCollection.getEnumerator();
        var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
        var webName = web.get_title(); 
        alert(webName);
    }

Comment: Fine! I'm happy for you :) If you can share your code, maybe we could help you

Comment: I edited my question and pasted my code. Could you help me to execute this code automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var contextWeb = clientContext.get_web();
var webCollection = contextWeb.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
clientContext.load(webCollection);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function () {
        // console.log('success :)');
        var webEnumerator = webCollection.getEnumerator();
        var subsites = [];
        while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
            var title = web.get_title();
            var url = web.get_url()
            var logoUrl = web.get_siteLogoUrl();
            var description = web.get_description();

            subsites.push({url: url, title: title, description: description, logoUrl: logoUrl});
        }
        // console.log(subsites)
        // do stuff to reorder
        var firstSiteUrl = subsites[0].url;
        // do stuff to redirect
        // console.log(firstSiteUrl);
    },
    function () {
        // log failure
        // console.log('error :(');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but I just adapted previous code to work fine. Your guidelines were very useful to me and I achieved an appropriate solution to my case.

Comment: I improved my working solution by replacing get_title() to get_url() and it works really better - especially in a situation when subsite title is different than the site URL ending, it never redirects any user. Now it's universal by getting url instead of subsite title. Thank you again!